# How can a micro-payara instance be bound to localhost only?

Tags: java, networking, command-line, payara-micro

I want to run a micro-payara on the localhost interface only. How can I manage that?

I didn't find any command line options:
https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/documentation/payara-micro/appendices/cmd-line-opts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, there's no command line option to specify the address on command line. You have to go a bit deeper and specify a command file with the `--prebootcommandfile` option.

The command file (let's call it `commands.txt`) should contain the following line:

```
set configs.config.server-config.network-config.network-listeners.network-listener.http-listener.address=localhost
```

The command-line to apply that file is:

```
java -jar payara-micro.jar --prebootcommandfile commands.txt
```

Comment: That didn't work for me with payara micro `5.194`. Maybe the config option has changed?

Comment: Well, I found out it did. But in the log output `Instance Configuration` is showing the FQDN of the host, which I wouldn't expect in this situation. Or am I wrong about that?